# DisallowedHost at / Invalid HTTP_HOST header: [IP] ; You may need to add [IP] to ALLOWED_HOSTS

Tags: django, supervisord

I want to deploy my Django app and I already used gunicorn, nginx and supervisor and stored on AWS EC2

Here is the snippet of my settings.py

```
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['<my_ip>', '<my_ip>.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com']
```

I have settings_prod.py and settings_dev.py

settings_prod.py

```
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    '<my_ip>', '<my_ip>.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com']
```

From my wsgi.py

```
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'votingapp.settings_prod')
```

I put the correct host address and it still got the same error:

```
Exception Type: DisallowedHost
Exception Value:    
Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '<ip>'. You may need to add '<ip>' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
```

The problem is it uses settings from settings_dev.py which is not my ideal sequence. I want the supervisor or settings_dev.py to allow my IP to host the site.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Add your IP in ALLOWED HOSTS

```
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    'your IP',
]
```

Then your can run your server as
`python manage.py runserver yourIP:port`

Comment: nope i'm using settings_prod and settings_dev.. running in supervisor, it redirects to settings_dev,. supervisor should run using settings_prod that has a dedicated IP in it but returned none. I also put environment variables in [supervisord]

Comment: Bad idea, is not good to allow users direct access via IP, it creates a vulnerability trespassing TLS certificates

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and I've solved it with following steps:

1. I use .env files with my project (for managing it I use `python-decouple` package);
2. I separate all my settings to dev and prod py files with base common python file.
3. Next, I import all settings from .base, .dev and .prod and manage them with `PROJECT` env var (if env var set to dev, use dev settings).

__init__.py file:

```
from .base import *

if config("PROJECT") == "prod":
    from .prod import *
else:
    from .dev import *
```

`config` set in base.py:

```
from decouple import AutoConfig

PROJECT_ROOT = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
BASE_DIR = PROJECT_ROOT.parent

ENV_FILE_PATH = BASE_DIR.parent / '.env'
config = AutoConfig(ENV_FILE_PATH)
```

structure of settings sub-package in my django project:

```
...
settings
  ├── __init__.py
  ├── base.py
  ├── dev.py
  └── prod.py
```

If you use AWS ES2, then you probably already have env vars in your project, so you can just replace `python-decouple` by your solution (like os.environ as default) and then manage your settings with your custom setted env var.

Comment: I've faced with this problem right now. If above answer is not a solution, try to check, what value contains in ALLOWED_HOSTS variable (`print(ALLOWED_HOSTS)` in settings). In my current case, Django for some reason have no values in ALLOWD_HOSTS, even if I have it. Try to reload you PC)